# font not consistance across differnet Operation system/different machines

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, font-face

I am using "Populaire" font. I am having a weird problem.

When I view the font in laptop, fonts are clearly formed without any distortion (on all browsers) but when the same was seen on other systems(not all but few systems do), it started appearing distorted (again, on all browsers). I am not sure what will cause the font to be distorted in some systems. Please advice.  Here is the CSS that I have used in my code..

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Populaire';
src: url('font/populaire.eot');
src: url('font/populaire.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('font/populaire.woff') format('woff'),
     url('font/populaire.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('font/![enter image description here][2]populaire.svg#populaire') format('svg');
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Populaire','Helvetica neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 2em;
font-weight:lighter;
color: #ffffff;
background-color: #8D407C;
width:250px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Without screenshots to demonstrate the problem it's hard to tell exactly what you mean by "distorted".

Comment: This is how it looks (which is the correct format)
http://www.imgplace.com/viewimg99/1087/56machine1.png

This is how it displays in some machines (distorted fonts)
http://www.imgplace.com/viewimg17/6453/39machine2.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type in your second screenshot is being displayed without anti-aliasing. This might occur because the second computer does not have Cleartype enabled.

http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartype/tuner/step1.aspx

In Windows Vista, Windows 7, and OSX Cleartype (or an equivalent anti-aliasing engine) is enabled by default.

Without anti-aliasing, any typeface that has not been specifically hinted for on-screen display will appear 'jaggy', since its curves do not neatly fit to the screen's pixel grid.

Comment: You are "genuis", Thanks for the answer!! so just want to make it clear that, there is no issue with my code (setup) and I do not need to change anything in the code. this has to be done by the user (cleartype changes) in their machine? thanks again for the answer, it really worked!!

Comment: That's right - it is the user's responsibility. I don't believe there is any way for a web developer to turn Cleartype on or off.